# How to delete one line in a specific commit on github?

Tags: git, github

I'm currently working on a project with Github on a private repository.

I made a mistake last friday while pushing my code on my repo and I would like to delete 2 specifics lines (which contains sentsitive information)

I would like to know if it is possible to delete 2 lines (number 458 / 459 on a specific file) from the history, which would mean no trace at all from these information ?

I tried multiple stuff but it never worked and since I pushed more changes, so my commit is behind other.

Is there any way to do so ?

Thank's !

Comment: You pushed this file and those lines, so the cat is out of the bag.  Even if you completely scrub your local history and the history on the remote, there is still a chance that someone else has already pulled.  If these lines contain sensitive things like passwords etc. then you should change them immediately.  Otherwise, just live with this information being out there.

Comment: No one actually pulled since I'm working alone on this, but It will change, that's why i'm asking.

Comment: If it is the last commit, you could use `git commit --amend` to rewrite the last commit, followed by `git push --force-with-lease`.

Comment: You can amend your last commit locally (git commit --amend). However, in most cases the remote will reject your push afterwards. https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history

Comment: My commit is not the last one =/

Comment: @Nicolas_LeBot: it can still be done, it's just slightly more involved. Read the "rewriting history" link, it explains at least the concept. Since you're working alone the "rewriting history is bad" part isn't as big as an issue here (or put differently: only you have to learn how to work around that).

Comment: @Nicolas_LeBot https://stackoverflow.com/a/22959057/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+modify+old+commit

Comment: @JoachimSauer I did it :) Thank for the tips everyone ! :)

Comment: Note that even after you push some replacement commit(s), GitHub will hang on to, and serve, the old commits to anyone who asks and has permission. Whether and when this is a problem depends on the data that's in those old commits. GitHub will *eventually* "forget" the old commits, but there's no way for us ordinary users to predict *when*. You can—especially for paid GitHub accounts—ask the GitHub folks to speed this up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose you have just pushed to the remote, so:

1. Issue `git log` to retrieve the commit hash, which we will label as COMMIT_HASH.
2. Issue `git rebase -i  COMMIT_HASH~1`.
3. The text editor will popup, so change the action to **edit**, save and close the editor.
4. Make changes to your file(s).
5. Issue `git add --all`.
6. Issue `git rebase --continue`.
7. Issue, **IF ARE YOU SURE**, `git push --force`.